# IntelliJ IDEA won't stop on assertions in debug mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Why won't IntelliJ IDEA stop in debug mode when an assertion is triggered? I get a `java.lang.AssertionError` to console, but the running code doesn't pause at it as it is supposed to. Here are my exception breakpoints settings:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/kiMwLfb.png]

Comment: try to change 'thread' radio to 'all'

Comment: @Rafik991 No, that's not the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that somehow debugger doesn't stop on assertions when running *tests*, but it does stop when running other code. The code I was trying to make stop on a failed assertion in debug mode was a test. That seems to be the issue, but I don't understand why would IDE behave that way.

Comment: Still encountering this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Open source code of AssertionError and put a breakpoint on the constructor it will stop.
[image]